# Can I bind data to a root Component?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript1.5

I am experimenting with Angular 2 and I tried to bind data to my root ( or application ) component, which is the one being bootstrapped. But I always get undefined inside it. It wouldn't be a big issue in most cases as we could always encapsulate the component we need to get the data into another component. But in the case of an application component I think it would be good to be able to pass data to it like arguments to a program.

Anyways, here is some code illustrating the issue :

```
index.html
----------
<body>

    <app-component p="ok">

    </app-component>
    <script>

        System.import('AppComponent');

    </script>

</body>

AppComponent.ts
---------------
/// <reference path="typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />

import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';

@Component({
    selector:'app-component',
    properties:'p'
})
@View({
    template: "<h1>test : {{ p }}</h1>"
})
class AppComponent {

}

bootstrap(AppComponent);
```

In this code, p is always undefined, is there any way to get this working?

Comment: See this https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/1858, it doesn't seem to have been fixed. So you could comment on that issue to get their attention since it is still open.